# How to use windows task scheduler to run Python *.py with input parameter in Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, windows

I have a python file( python_test.py) and I want to run the file by windows task scheduler because if the execution is stopped by errors I want the scheduler to check and run the Python file.
However, my python_test.py is executed with input parameter in command line, ex. python python_test.py 0
ex. python python_test.py 1
ex. python python_test.py 2
I haven’t found the way to execute my Python file with parameter by windows task scheduler on Anaconda.

Does anyone have the idea?

I try to set the task scheduler but it’s not working.

Comment: Write a .cmd file, and run that with the task scheduler.